# XSD to validate a list of 1 to 4 specific characters

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would like to validate that an attribute value in my XML contains at least one character and up to 4 characters in a set.  The values I'm looking for are "T", "C", "S" and "R".  They can be in any order and combination, must be at least one of these characters and may be all four of them.

I've created a long list with all of the possible combinations, below, using enumerations.  I would like to simplify this with some pattern checking.

```
<xs:attribute name="valid-types" use="required">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">   
        <xs:enumeration value="T"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="R"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="TS"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="TC"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="TR"/>
        <!-- and so on  -->
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

In the end, acceptable XML values would be "T", or "TC" or "TSC" or "TSCR" or any other combination of TSCR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `xs:pattern` with a regex:

```
<xs:attribute name="valid-types" use="required">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[TCSR]{1,4}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Comment: Works like I expected.  Thank you.  Wonder now if there is an easy way to assure that none of the letter are repeated.  The code that reads these values in would not care.  It would be for the configuration writer, to identify a possible mistake.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: XSD 1.1 could enforce no duplicates with assertions.